# displaying different content on each row of query result

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

My model code

```
function wife($a){

$sql="select person.person_id,person.new_surname,person.fname,person.father_name,person.village,marriage.wife_id from person left join marriage on person.person_id=marriage.wife_id where marriage.husband_id='$a'";
        $query=$this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->result();


}
```

My view code

```
<?php
 foreach($result as $row){
echo  "first".$row->fname;
echo  $row->father_name
echo  $row->new_surname;
    echo  $row->village;
?>
```

for first row i want to display above and for second row i want to display following

```
<?php
 foreach($result as $row){
echo  "Second".$row->fname;
echo  $row->father_name
echo  $row->new_surname;
    echo  $row->village;
?>
```

Comment: do you have more than 2 row? or only two rows?

Comment: it can be 1 or 2 or 3 also.

Comment: I think you got solution.

Comment: no..i tried that but it, not working for me..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach($result as $row){
    if ($i == 0) {
        echo "first" . $row->fname;
    } else if ($i == 1) {
        echo "Second" . $row->fname;
    } else {
        // Do this for third etc. rows
    }
    echo  $row->father_name
    echo  $row->new_surname;
    echo  $row->village;
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: if $i=0 then i want to display whole info fname,father_name,etc..and when $i=1 then also i want display whole information fname,father_name,etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can take Variable i and convert number to string using any function which can be used without hard coded strings and will work for n numbers